# Bootstrap 4 card too responsive when wrapping table

Tags: bootstrap-4

If I wrap a card around a table  and shrink the page down to phone size such that the table forces a horizontal scroll bar to view it all, then the responsive card ignores the table sizing (essentially a minimum width) and resizes to fit the window so the card is then smaller than the table it is supposed to contain.

How do I force the card to always wrap around the table?

Live example below - at small phone size the right edge of the card goes through the middle of the column/word "Notes"

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card ">
        <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead">
            <tr class="atr">
              <th class="ath" >Name</th>
              <th class="ath" >Destination</th>
              <th class="ath" >Priority</th>
              <th class="ath" >Notes</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone interested the answer is to add class clearfix to the wrapping div
as in

```
<div class="card clearfix">
```

Now the card is always on the outside of the contents.